# Calculate a min over multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

Say I have a table `events` that looks like this

```
id    start   end
1     12:09   12:12
2     12:07   12:09
3     12:07   12:08
```

I want to get the minimum start time with the minimum id. The reason I need the id for a reference to the row later to retrieve the `end` column.

In this example, that would be (12:07, 2).

I know that one way of getting this is to retrieve the minimum `start` first and then take the min `id` of that, like this:

```
select min (e.id) as minId from events as e 
join (
  select min (start) as minStart from events
) as x
where e.start = x.minStart
group by e.start
```

But is there a way to get both in one

(no subquery)? Like,

```
select min (start, id) as (minStart, minId) from events
```

Obviously not that since that's not valid syntax, but something in that spirit?

**Follow-up**

As Gordon suggested below, when running `order by start, id limit 1`, mysql does use the index. Here's what the EXPLAIN looks like when the `limit 1` is included:

```
1   SIMPLE  events  index   NULL    startId     5   NULL    1   NULL
```

and here's what it looks like without the `limit 1`:

```
1   SIMPLE  events  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    640     Using filesort
```

Comment: The minimum start time with id would be (1, 12:05).

Comment: @Gordon Oops, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
select e.*
from events e
order by start_time, id
limit 1;
```

This gives you all the fields in the record.

Note:  It does only return one record, even if there are duplicates.  This seems to be your intention.

If you want the *maximum* start time with the minimum id (which is what the sample data suggests):

```
select e.*
from events e
order by start_time desc, id asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: If I wanted to do `order by start, id`, would sort of index do you think I should have on the table to make it efficient? Does mysql use an index to do an order by? Would it be smart about the order by limit 1 or would it normally just do sort of the whole table and then limit it by 1?

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton . . . You would use an index on `events(start_time, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from events 
order by start_time,id
limit 1;
```